# Error with React Routing, "[AuthProvider] is not a <Route> component. All component children of <Routes> must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

React Routing seems way overly complicated, I have authentication through Firebase and need the routes wrapped with the `<AuthProvider>` but I get this error that it's not a part of the `<Route>` component. I can't find a work around for this. How is routing supposed to work in React? Here's my app.tsx:

```
import Posts, { postsLoader } from "./components/pages/Posts";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <AuthProvider>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />} loader={postsLoader} />
          <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
          <Route
            path="/dashboard"
            element={
              <WithPrivateRoute>
                <Dashboard />
              </WithPrivateRoute>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </AuthProvider>
  )
);

function App() {
  return <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>;
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

## Issues

- `createRoutesFromElements` only accepts `Route` and `React.Fragments` components.
- `createBrowserRouter` creates the router so trying to render a nested `Router` isn't valid.

## Solution

Update your `AuthProvider` component to wrap the `RouterProvider` component in `App` and remove the extraneous `Router` and `Routes` components as they are unnecessary.

```
import Posts, { postsLoader } from "./components/pages/Posts";

const router = createBrowserRouter(
  createRoutesFromElements(
    <>
      <Route path="/posts" element={<Posts />} loader={postsLoader} />
      <Route path="/signin" element={<SignIn />} />
      <Route
        path="/dashboard"
        element={
          <WithPrivateRoute>
            <Dashboard />
          </WithPrivateRoute>
        }
      />
    </>
  )
);

function App() {
  return (
    <AuthProvider>
      <RouterProvider router={router} />
    </AuthProvider>
  );
}
```